# Improper integral converges or not

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, absolute-convergence, divergent-integrals

Find all the values $\alpha \in(0,\infty)$ such that the improper integral $$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\Bbb dx}{1+x^{\alpha}\sin^2x}$$ is convergent.

My attempt is to analyze the cases (i) $\alpha =1$, (ii) $\alpha >1$, and $\alpha <1$.

The case (i) gives divergence. I don’t know how to handle the other two cases. Does anyone have any suggestions for these cases?

Comment: Can you write out your work with $\alpha=1$?

Comment: well, for case $\alpha=1$, we have $\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{dx}{1+x\sin^2x} \geq \int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{dx}{1+x}$. Because $\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{dx}{1+x}$ diverges, it means that for case $\alpha =1$, the improper integral diverges, right?

Comment: Do you think that you can use the same idea for the rest?

Comment: I think it can be reused to finish the case $\alpha<1$ also (hence in this case the improper integral diverges). But for $\alpha>1$, I don't think so, because $\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{dx}{1+x^\alpha}$ converges.

Comment: Can you compare your integrand with $1/(x^{\alpha}\sin ^2x)$, and then possibly use by parts?

Comment: hmm, I don't think so